# ogg.framework missing arm64e binary/library (m1 mac)

Tags: macos, gaming, shared-libraries

So im trying to run a game that was compiled from source and it required dependencies such as `libogg`. When i compiled the game and try to run it, an error occured

```
dyld[26732]: Library not loaded: @rpath/../Frameworks/ogg.framework/Versions/A/ogg
  Referenced from: /Users/jason/Games/unnamed-sdvx-clone/bin/usc-game
  Reason: tried: '/Library/Frameworks/ogg.framework/Versions/A/ogg' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/System/Library/Frameworks/ogg.framework/Versions/A/ogg' (no such file)
zsh: abort      ./usc-game
```

**I made an issue in the game's github repository and i was told it was a system issue, so i came here**

I then checked the file using `file ogg`

```
ogg: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [i386:Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386] [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64]
ogg (for architecture i386):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
ogg (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

turns out i did not have the native arm version of this framework and I need some help getting the arm build of this framework, or some information regarding this framework to resolve the issue...

Comment: There is a good chance there will be other libraries that this project uses that will need to be recompiled to support ARM64.  Have you recompile ogg.framework yourself to support ARM64? You will have to recompile any dependencies that ogg.framework might use to also support ARM64. What your asking for isn’t something one person does typically

Comment: @Ramhound I solved my issue. I had to copy the libraries from `/usr/local/lib` to the framework directory and it fixed my issue. **they were the universal libraries**. there was no need to compile the frameworks to support arm64.. thanks for your help anyway